# How to make an If Statement into a For Loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I am making a project in VBA and I face a problem with the following code...

It says there is a object or an undefined function, but I don't understand why... Any Idea of what the problem is?

(All the variables are declared and i checked the name of the sheets)

```vb
Set FinalRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Fiche Horaire").Range("A:A")
emptyroww = WorksheetFunction.CountA(FinalRange)

precautionroww = 0
If emptyroww > 50 Then precautionroww = emptyroww - 50

For a = precautionroww To emptyroww
    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Fiche Horaire").Cells(a, 1).Value = name Then ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Fiche Horaire").Cells(a, 4).Value = "it works"
Next
```

The message it gives is "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: `a` starts with 0 and row numbers start with 1. Also calling a variable `name` is not he best idea.

Comment: Where exactly does the error occur? have you tried stepping through the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your precautionroww is 0 because your emptyrow is below 50 you try to insert your data in row 0 which is causing the error

Thats a problem within VBA if you have a for loop and start with the same value as your "end" value than i still runs 1 time.

Comment: I changed it so precautionroww value is either 1 either emptyrow - 50 and it works :) Thanks a lot, beginner's mistake I suppose.